# cStringIO.StringIO() is not working

Tags: python, django

I am trying to convert rml to pdf using,

```
import cStringIO
buf = cStringIO.StringIO()
rml2pdf.go(rml, outputFileName=buf)
buf.reset()
pdfData = buf.read()
response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/pdf')
response.write(pdfData)
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=output.pdf'
return response
```

But I am getting error saying `No module named cStringIO`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cStringIO is not available in your environment.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
try:
  from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
  from StringIO import StringIO
```

**Update**

For Python 3, please use this io module and BytesIO class:

```
from io import BytesIO
```

Comment: Now getting `No module named StringIO`

Comment: Is `from io import StringIO    buf = StringIO()` is same

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Python 64 bit 3.4. Sorry new to Python

Comment: Thanks. But I am getting now `object has no attribute reset `

Comment: instead of buf.reset() and pdfData = buf.read() use pdfData = buf.getvalue()

Comment: Thanks. I have used seek(0). Its working now. Because I used seek(0) in .NET